# mongodb throwing error while saving data (topology destroyed)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to write data to MongoDB using Node.js
While writing the data, I am getting the following error in the last line.
Execution logs are:

```
{ _id: 56e90c1292e69900190954f5, 
nfs: [ 'ebdp1', 'ebdp2', 'ebdp3', 'ebdp4' ],
snapShotTime: '2016-03-16 07:32:34' }
{ [MongoError: topology was destroyed] name: 'MongoError', message: 'topology was destroyed' }
```

My code structure is according to the framework, where Collection's schema is in `appTableProdSchema.js` file, and the Object data in `appTableProdData.js` file. 
The Main is newMain.js

Code is as follows:
newMain.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var moment = require('moment');
var nfs_check="";
var promises = [];

var nodes = ["ebdp1","ebdp2", "ebdp3", "ebdp4"];

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');
var db = mongoose.connection;
var storageData = require('./appTableProdData.js');
var storageDataSchema = require('./appTableProdSchema.js');
var obj = {};
obj.snapShotTime = moment().utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
obj.nfs = nodes;
db.once('open', function() {
    var mongoData = new storageData();
    mongoData.fill(obj);
    var promise = new storageDataSchema(mongoData.getInformation());
    console.log(promise.toString());
    promise.save(function (err, promise) {
            if (err) return console.error(err);
            promise.speak();
        }); 
});
mongoose.disconnect();
```

appTableProdSchema.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('AppTableProd', {
    snapShotTime : String,
    nfs: Array    
});
```

appTableProdData.js

```
var storageData = function() {
    this.data =  {
            snapShotTime: null,
            nfs: null    
    };
    this.fill = function(resp) {
        this.data.snapShotTime = resp.snapShotTime;
        this.data.nfs = resp.nfs;
    };
    this.getInformation = function() {
        return this.data;
    };
};
module.exports = storageData;
```

Any idea why am i getting  `topology destroyed` error ?
Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your

```
mongoose.disconnect();
```

is getting called before

```
db.once('open', function() {
var mongoData = new storageData();
mongoData.fill(obj);
var promise = new storageDataSchema(mongoData.getInformation());
console.log(promise.toString());
promise.save(function (err, promise) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        promise.speak();
    }); 
});
```

this code block is getting executed as it is a async call.

you should call this

```
mongoose.disconnect();
```

like this

```
 db.once('open', function() {
var mongoData = new storageData();
mongoData.fill(obj);
var promise = new storageDataSchema(mongoData.getInformation());
console.log(promise.toString());
promise.save(function (err, promise) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        promise.speak();
       mongoose.disconnect();
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem, mongoose is running asynchronously, you cant use `mongoose.disconnect();` at the end of the script, this is a synchronous way.

`Topology destroyed` signifies that you are closing the connection in the same time when you try to insert something in the database. This is the behavior of nodejs that he is starting (in parallel all asynchronous processes).

In this case try to remove `mongoose.disconnect();`. Or make sure there are no asynchronous calls to mongodb before closing the connection.

Comment: I removed mongoose.disconnect(); but still the same problem. :(

Comment: hi @aiman, I have the same problem but with loopback, it uses own mongodb connector which uses native mongodb driver for node.js, I am not sure what to do with it, did you find a solution?

Comment: yes the solution is provided above by "Mustafa Mamun"